# Storage provider not working

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I am trying to add a component in Ionic. However following the official guide seems to give me errors.

https://ionicframework.com/docs/storage/

I only changed two files, *app.module.ts*

Added module

```
import { IonicStorageModule } from '@ionic/storage';
```

Added provider

```
providers: [
StatusBar,
SplashScreen,
{provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler},
IonicStorageModule
```

]

In my page *home.ts* I added;

```
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';
```

Edited the constructor;

```
 constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private storage: Storage) {}
```

Then I added a function to set the data;

```
setData() {
    this.storage.set('myData','hello');
}
```

The result I get a error

```
Uncaught (in promise): Error: No provider for Storage!
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add it to the **imports list** in your NgModule declaration as follows,

```
imports: [      
    .........
    IonicStorageModule.forRoot()
  ],
```

Not into the providers list